# Is this ERD appropriate for powerBI?

Tags: powerbi, database-administration, erd

I am a data analyst working for a community college, I am self-teaching power bi and I am trying to set up a relational database to organize the student and class data I have received so that I can more easily conduct analysis in power bi. Will this ERD work to conduct a 5 year analysis of student performance? (See attached image)

[image: ERD]

I have worked in Power BI just using the large excel files I receive, but I am learning that setting up correct tables and relationships will make my analysis easier and more powerful. I am the sole analyst in this department and a new grad so I am learning on the fly.

Comment: No. PBI expects a proper star schema (a dimensional model). Your ERD is a typical data model for a regular relational database. There is a big difference between these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Close.  Merge "Student Type" into Enrolment, adding the StudentType, Campus, ... into the Enrollment table.  Those two tables have the same grain (Semester Code, Student ID), so they should be one table.

Enrollment becomes your fact table, and the other tables are dimensions.